Как исправить ошибку JS
Есть код
var objectsCSV = '\n51.5406;46.0086;"от 4909р.";"в Саратов ";\n51.83;107.606;"от 10600р.";"в Улан-Удэ ";\n59.5339;30.1850;"от 3221р.";"в Санкт-Петербург ";\n55.7887;49.1221;"от 3934р.";"в Казань ";\n43.5992;39.7257;"от 4286р.";"в Сочи";\n43.1056;131.874;"от 18100р.";"во Владивосток";\n53.9;27.56;"от 6170р.";"в Минск ";\n55.04;82.9346;"от 8159р.";"в Новосибирск ";\n54.99;73.36;"от 8159р.";"в Омск ";\n55.154;61.4291;"от 4909р.";"в Челябинск ";\n54.7065;20.511;"от 4009р.";"в Калининград ";\n48.7194;44.5018;"от 3609р.";"в Волгоград ";';
var objects = objectsCSV.split('\n');

ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
            center: [53.03,67.37],
            zoom: 4}
      );
    
        for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
            object = objects[i].split(';');
            
        var placemark = new ymaps.Placemark([object[0], object[1]], {
            balloonContent: object[3]+' <a href="/flights/?origin_iata=MOW&destination_iata=AER&depart_date=2024-11-26&return_date=2024-12-13&marker=87111&with_request=true"" id="block">Поиск билета</a>',
            iconCaption: object[2]
        }, {
            preset: 'islands#violetDotIconWithCaption'
        });
            placemark.balloon.events.add('click', function(e) {
                e.get('target').balloon.close();
            })
            myMap.geoObjects.add(placemark);
        }
}

Задача в ссылку после знака вопроса вставить object[3], то-бишь вот так /flights/?object[3]+origin_iata=MOW&destination_iata=AER&depart_date=2024-11-26&return_date=2024-12-13&marker=87111&with_request=true"" id="block">Поиск билета Но выдается ошибка, не может идентифицировать object[3], таких объектов будет несколько и объект 5 и объект 6 в будущем. Подскажите как его правильно вставить.

не может идентифицировать object[3] - Поясните, что это значит? Какой результат вы получаете сейчас и какой ожидаете? Так же, обратите внимание, что 1-й элемент вашего objects - пустая строка

@SwaD codepen.io/sochi-russia/pen/yLmWVqW вот что удалось сделать, но если на балун нажать, появляется ссылка, посмотрите на путь ссылки он на объекте 3 обрубается

Уберите у object[3] кавычки и ссылка должна формироваться нормально. Ломается из-за кавычек. После objects[i].split(';') добавьте строку object[3] = object[3]?.replaceAll('"', ''); или уберите кавычки из исходных данных

@SwaD Я сейчас не возле компьютера, чуть позже проверю и отпишусь, Вам. Оформите пожалуйста ответом

@SwaD Спасибо огромное!

@SwaD здравствуйте, столкнулся с такой проблемой, что в мобильной версии Click по ссылке не срабатывает, предполагаю что Click перехватывается, в ПК версии на карте клик работает и переходит по ссылке, не подскажите как решить данную проблему?

Не знаю. Оформите новый вопрос с указанием этой проблемы. Возможно @yasupport сможет помочь, он вроде как раз помогает с яндекс-картами, возможно это "фича" яндекс карт...

@SwaD спасибо за инфу

Выше верно указали — вам следует убрать кавычки. И просто object[3] в вашем случае — странный query-параметр, быть может, вы планировали сделать что-то вида «route_to=в Омск»? Без кавычек это работает.

@YaSupport здравствуйте, спасибо за информацию, все работает, но по данному коду возникла проблема, я озвучил ее в другом моем вопросе, можете туда заглянуть? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1600368/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%af%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0
