При клике по ссылке в балуне Яндекс Карт не происходит перехода
Есть код  https://codepen.io/sochi-russia/pen/yLmWVqW
var objectsCSV = '\n51.5406;46.0086;"от 4909р.";"в Саратов ";"RTW"\n51.83;107.606;"от 10600р.";"в Улан-Удэ ";"UUD"\n59.5339;30.1850;"от 3221р.";"в Санкт-Петербург ";"LED";\n55.7887;49.1221;"от 3934р.";"в Казань ";"KZN";\n43.5992;39.7257;"от 4286р.";"в Сочи";"AER";\n43.1056;131.874;"от 18100р.";"во Владивосток";"VVO"\n53.9;27.56;"от 6170р.";"в Минск ";"MSQ";\n55.04;82.9346;"от 8159р.";"в Новосибирск ";"OVB";\n54.99;73.36;"от 7009р.";"в Омск ";"OMS";\n55.154;61.4291;"от 4909р.";"в Челябинск ";"CEK";\n54.7065;20.511;"от 4009р.";"в Калининград ";"KGD";\n48.7194;44.5018;"от 3609р.";"в Волгоград ";"VOG";';
var objects = objectsCSV.split('\n');

ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
            center: [53.03,67.37],
            zoom: 4}
      );

    // Получаем текущую дату в формате YYYY-MM-DD
    var currentDate = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];

    for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        var object = objects[i].split(';');
        object[4] = object[4]?.replaceAll('"', '');

        var placemark = new ymaps.Placemark([object[0], object[1]], {
            balloonContent: object[3] + 
            '<br><a class="but" href="/flights/?origin_iata=MOW&destination_iata=' + object[4] + 
            '&depart_date=' + currentDate + '&with_request=true"" id="block">Поиск билета</a>',
            iconCaption: object[2]
        }, {
            preset: 'islands#violetDotIconWithCaption'
        });

        placemark.balloon.events.add('click', function(e) {
            e.get('target').balloon.close();
        });

        myMap.geoObjects.add(placemark);
    }
}

Не кликается кнопка "Поиск билета" в мобильной версии Яндекс Карт, при клике закрывается окно, в ПК версии переход по ссылке происходит. Подскажите как исправить ситуацию?

В вашем случае мешает слушатель клика на балуне, который при тапе закрывает его раньше срабатывания ссылки. Если не хотите делать отдельную кнопку для закрытия балуна, можно делать это кликом по самой карте:
myMap.events.add('click', function(e) {
  e.get('target').balloon.close();
});


Спасибо огромное! Все заработало!

А можно вас спросить как сделать, чтобы при открытии балуна рядом с кнопкой высвечивалась температура в городе или рядом с балуном?

Можете добавить в балун любую нужную вам информацию. В API Яндекс Карт этих данных нет, потому источник будет нужно выбрать сторонний.

спасибо большое
